# HibernateTransactionManager error in Spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

HI,

I'm trying to add user to to Database from Spring MVC controller.  and I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

My code is the following:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/doolloop2" />
  <property name="username" value="doolloop2" />
  <property name="password" value="doolloop" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
     <property name="mappingLocations">
      <list>
        <value>WEB-INF/mapping/User.hbm.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
 <props>
  <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop> 
  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
  <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
  </props>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="txService" class="com.doolloop.services.TxDataBaseServiceImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Then my Service looks like this:

```
public class TxDataBaseServiceImpl implements TxDataBaseService {

 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public void setSessionFactory (SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
       this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

 @Override
 @Transactional
 public void add(User user) {
  Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

   Transaction tr = session.getTransaction();
     tr.begin();
     session.save(user);
     tr.commit();
 }    
}
```

Now on my Servlet I'm wiring the class

```
 @Autowired
 private TxDataBaseServiceImpl service;



     @RequestMapping(value="/signup.dlp",method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public ModelAndView addUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result){
        logger.info("Return View");
        registrationValidation.validate(user, result);
                /// all required validations....
      service.add(user);
       ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/Accounts/signupSuccess");
       return mv;
    }
```

The question is what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot `<tx:annotation-driven>`?

Comment: This isn't what's actually causing the error you're getting, but one is puzzled as to why you're using a declarative transaction on the method, then going and trying to programatically manage the transaction inside the method as well?

Comment: @axtavt - I do have <mvc:annotation-driven /> in my code. @Affe - Could you please clarify that?

Comment: To enable `@Transactional` you need `<tx:annotation-driven>`, not `<mvc:annotation-driven>`. Also, if `@Transactional` works properly, you don't need to `begin()` and `commit()` transaction manually (that's the point of Affe's comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the error:

```
@Autowired
private TxDataBaseServiceImpl service;
```

You are trying to autowire the implementation class instead of the interface, and hence you get the raw bean injected, not the transactional proxy. Do it like this:

```
@Autowired
private TxDataBaseService service;
```

Always prefer coding against interfaces because a) Joshua Bloch says so :-) and b) a lot of the functionality in Spring is built upon interfaces.

Comment: Unfortunately, it hasn't helped :(

Comment: See axtavt's comments above. If you follow that advice (add tx:annotation-driven and lose the begin / commit transaction) then it should work.